# Hosting an Ionic 4 and angular Wpa SPA in a IIS server

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, ionic4, web-deployment

I have a WPA app with ionic 4 and angular.

I am "forced" to host this app in to an IIS server that we already have. I cant find any documentation at all. Some say to follow the angular deploy documentation, but the problem is that the ionic project has no web config file.

Then they say to make a url rewrite. I downloaded a plugin for IIS for that but i jsut cant get it to work. What rewrite with what?

The base href is "/" empty. What alias should i use?

The ionic build --base-href does not work either.

I would really need some help on that.

Comment: I don't get your problem. What are the steps that you have followed?
From my perspective, once you have do `ionic build --prod` this will create a folder with your assets. Those assets will need to be placed in the folder of your project where your index file it is supposed to be, then in the IIS select the public folder the same as your index file and that should work

Comment: After i do the build it creates a www folder with the index inside. The problem is that in iis most of the times returns 404 instead of the site when you visit it from the browser, and it serves you the site when you visit it from the iis. This is a common problem as i can see. But i cant find a sollution clear enought for me to follow.

Comment: But is it loading the website or not? When is giving you this 404 errors? I think you need to provide more information

Comment: I suggest you check the IIS log for the more information which status code and sub status code it shows. if your site is not shows anything when you visit in the browser then you could try to run this command: `ionic cordova build browser --prod` or `ionic build browser --prod` Then you need to use what is inside platforms/browser/www.